# R - How to replicate rows in a spark dataframe using sparklyr

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparklyr

Is there a way to replicate the rows of a Spark's dataframe using the functions of sparklyr/dplyr?

```
sc <- spark_connect(master = "spark://####:7077")

df_tbl <- copy_to(sc, data.frame(row1 = 1:3, row2 = LETTERS[1:3]), "df")
```

This is the desired output, saved into a new spark tbl:

```
> df2_tbl
   row1  row2
  <int> <chr>
1     1     A
2     1     A
3     1     A
4     2     B
5     2     B
6     2     B
7     3     C
8     3     C
9     3     C
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `sparklyr` you can use `array` and `explode` as suggested by @Oli:

```
df_tbl %>% 
  mutate(arr = explode(array(1, 1, 1))) %>% 
  select(-arr)

# # Source:   lazy query [?? x 2]
# # Database: spark_connection
#    row1 row2 
#   <int> <chr>
# 1     1 A    
# 2     1 A    
# 3     1 A    
# 4     2 B    
# 5     2 B    
# 6     2 B    
# 7     3 C    
# 8     3 C    
# 9     3 C
```

and generalized

```
library(rlang)

df_tbl %>%  
  mutate(arr = !!rlang::parse_quo(
    paste("explode(array(", paste(rep(1, 3), collapse = ","), "))")
  )) %>% select(-arr)

# # Source:   lazy query [?? x 2]
# # Database: spark_connection
#    row1 row2 
#   <int> <chr>
# 1     1 A    
# 2     1 A    
# 3     1 A    
# 4     2 B    
# 5     2 B    
# 6     2 B    
# 7     3 C    
# 8     3 C    
# 9     3 C
```

where you can easily adjust number of rows.

Comment: BTW for newer versions of rlang, the environment is necessary to pass into `parse_quo`, and so you'd go `parse_quo(paste(...), env = sc)` where `sc` is the Spark context :)

Answer (score 1):

The idea that comes to mind first is to use the `explode` function (it is exactly what it is meant for in Spark). Yet arrays do not seem to be supported in SparkR (to the best of my knowledge).

```
> structField("a", "array")
Error in checkType(type) : Unsupported type for SparkDataframe: array
```

I can however propose two other methods:

1. A straightforward but not very elegant one:

   ```
   head(rbind(df, df, df), n=30)
   #    row1 row2
   # 1    1    A
   # 2    2    B
   # 3    3    C
   # 4    1    A
   # 5    2    B
   # 6    3    C
   # 7    1    A
   # 8    2    B
   # 9    3    C
   ```

   Or with a for loop for more genericity:

   ```
   df2 = df
   for(i in 1:2) df2=rbind(df, df2)
   ```

   Note that this would also work with `union`.
2. The second, more elegant method (because it only implies one spark operation) is based on a cross join (Cartesian product) with a dataframe of size 3 (or any other number):

   ```
   j <- as.DataFrame(data.frame(s=1:3))
   head(drop(crossJoin(df, j), "s"), n=100)
   #    row1 row2
   # 1    1    A
   # 2    1    A
   # 3    1    A
   # 4    2    B
   # 5    2    B
   # 6    2    B
   # 7    3    C
   # 8    3    C
   # 9    3    C
   ```

Comment: It should be `array<type>` not `array` for example `structField("a", "array<string>")` .

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a cluster side version of R's `rep`function. We can however use a join to emulate it cluster side.

```
df_tbl <- copy_to(sc, data.frame(row1 = 1:3, row2 = LETTERS[1:3]), "df")

replyr <- function(data, n, sc){
  joiner_frame <- copy_to(sc, data.frame(joiner_index = rep(1,n)), "tmp_joining_frame", overwrite = TRUE)

  data %>%
    mutate(joiner_index = 1) %>%
    left_join(joiner_frame) %>%
    select(-joiner_index)

}

df_tbl2 <- replyr(df_tbl, 3, sc)
#    row1 row2 
#    <int> <chr>
# 1     1 A    
# 2     1 A    
# 3     1 A    
# 4     2 B    
# 5     2 B    
# 6     2 B    
# 7     3 C    
# 8     3 C    
# 9     3 C
```

It gets the job done, but it is a bit dirty since the `tmp_joining_frame` will persist. I'm not sure how well this will work given lazy evaluation on multiple calls to the function.